# What user will Ansible run my commands as?

Tags: node.js, linux, git, ansible

### Background

My question seems simple, but it gets more complex really fast.

Basically, I got really tired of maintaining my servers manually *(screams in background)* and I decided it was time to find a way to make being a server admin much more liveable. That's when I found Ansible. Great huh? Sure beats making bash scripts *(louder scream)* for everything I wanted to automate.

### What's the problem?

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what user my Ansible playbook will run certain things as. I also need the ability to specify what user certain tasks will run as. Here are some specific use cases:

#### Cloning a repo as another user:

My purpose with this is it run my node.js webapp from another user, who we'll call *bill* (that can only use sudo to run a script that I made that starts the node server, as opposed to root or my user that can use sudo for all commands). To do this, I need the ability to have Ansible's git module clone my git repo as *bill*. How would I do that?

#### Knowing how Ansible will gain root:

As far as I understand, you can set what user Ansible will connect to the server you're maintaining by defining 'user' and the beginning of the playbook file. Here's what I don't understand: if I tell it to connect via my username, *joe*, and ask it to update a package via the apt module, how will it gain root? Sudo usually prompts me for my password, and I'd prefer keeping it that way (for security).

### Final request

I've scoured the Ansible docs, done some (what I thought was thorough) Googling, and generally just tried to figure it out on my own, but this information continues to elude me.

I am very new to Ansible, and while it's mostly straight-forwards, I would benefit greatly if I could understand exactly how Ansible runs, on which users it runs, and how/where I can specify what user to use at different times.

Thank you tons in advance

Comment: As you may have noticed, I tagged this with `python`, which may not be clear immediately. The reason I did that is because a very large portion of all Ansible modules are written in python.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may find it useful to read the Hosts and Users section on Ansible's documentation site:

http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

In summary, ansible will run all commands in a playbook as the user specified in the `remote_user` variable (assuming you're using ansible >= 1.4, `user` before that). You can specify this variable on a per-task basis as well, in case a task needs to run as a certain user.

Use `sudo: true` in any playbook/task to use `sudo` to run it. Use the `sudo_user` variable to specify a user to sudo to if you don't want to use `root`.

In practice, I've found it easiest to run my playbook as a `deploy` user that has sudo privileges. I set up my SSH keys so I can SSH into any host as `deploy` without using a password. This means that I can run my playbook without using a password and even use `sudo` if I need to.

I use this same user to do things like cloning git repos and starting/stopping services. If a service needs to run as a lower-privileged user, I let the init script take care of that. A quick Google search for a node.js init.d script revealed this one for CentOS:

https://gist.github.com/nariyu/1211413

Doing things this way helps to keep it simple, which I like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I also found this:
https://gist.github.com/marktheunissen/2979474

I found it pretty helpful, and while it was long, I recommend reading it, it really breaks down how Ansible works in an easy to understand way.

Comment: Here is one of the last snapshots of the above deprecated link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170716062706/http://docs.ansible.com:80/ansible/playbooks_intro.html

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents:

1. Ansible uses your local user (eg Mike) to ssh to the remote machine. (That required Mike to be able to ssh to the machine)
2. From there it can change to a remote user if needed
3. It can also sudo if needed and if Mike is allowed. If no user is specified then root will be selected via your `~/.ansible.cfg` on your local machine.
4. If you supply a remote_user with the sudo param then like no.3 it will not use root but that user.

You can specify different situations and different users or sudo via the [playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks.html).

Playbook's define which roles will be run into each machine that belongs to the inventory selected.

I suggest you read [Ansible best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) for some explanation on how to setup your infrastructure.

Oh and btw since you are not referring to a specific module that ansible uses and your question is not related to python, then I don't find any use your question having the python tag.

Comment: I think this is complicated if you're using another tool (e.g., vagrant) to manage ansible.  In that case, it seems to use a different user (e.g., 'ubuntu') for ssh access, but runs many tasks as root. The privilege escalation features worked for me, though.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note that Ansible>=1.9 uses privilege escalation commands so you can execute tasks and create resources as that secondary user if need be:

```
- name: Install software
  shell: "curl -s get.dangerous_software.install | sudo bash"
  become_user: root
```

https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/become.html

Comment: This works (btw become: true is really all you need) but it gets repetive really fast. If I have 10 tasks and 7 need sudo, I need this 7 times. Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: put all the tasks you need to do into a separate .yml file, and include it with become.

Comment: Link is broken...

Answer (score 0):

I notice current answers are a bit old and suffering from link rot.

Ansible will SSH as your current user, by default:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#connecting-to-remote-nodes

> Ansible communicates with remote machines over the SSH protocol. By default, Ansible uses native OpenSSH and connects to remote machines using your current user name, just as SSH does.

This can be overridden using:

> - passing the -u parameter at the command line
> - setting user information in your inventory file
> - setting user information in your configuration file
> - setting environment variables

But then you must ensure a route exists to SSH as that user. An approach to maintaining user-level ownership I see more often is `become` (root) and then to `chown -R jdoe:jdoe /the/file/path`.

In my 2.12 release of ansible I found the only way I could change the user was by specifying `become: yes` as an option at the play level. That way I am SSHing as the unprivileged, default, user. This user must have passwordless `sudo` enabled on the remote and is about the safest I could make my VPS. From this I could then switch to another user, with `become_user`, from an arbitrary command task.

Like this:

```
- name: Getting Started
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  become: yes  # All tasks that follow will become root.
  tasks:
  - name: get the username running the deploy
    command: echo $USER
    become_user: trubuntu  # From root we can switch to trubuntu.
```

If the user permitted SSH access to your remote is, say, `victor`, and not your current user, then `remote_user: victor` has a place at the play level, adjacent to `become: yes`.